# Serialize Nested JSON array in Unity3D

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a JSON file in Unity, but since the format of the JSON is an array that has some fields that are arrays, I'm really confused on how to go about doing it. I don't think that Unity's JsonUtility can work with nested arrays. I started looking into using MiniJSON to do it, but I'm not sure if it can handle this JSON format. Thanks in advance and any help would be appreciated!

I'm trying to serialize this JSON with C# in Unity:

```
{
    "people": [
    {
        "person_id": [-1],
        "pose_keypoints_2d": [529.088, 140.144, 0.81357, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 580.005, 222.377, 0.312258, 508.229, 452.092, 0.413092, 458.626, 313.751, 0.741145, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 536.951, 108.774, 0.829661, 0, 0, 0, 589.153, 78.7858, 0.81112, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        "face_keypoints_2d": [],
        "hand_left_keypoints_2d": [458.149, 315.774, 0.0320216, 459.031, 314.891, 0.0582551, 457.266, 321.954, 0.127813, 447.554, 292.819, 0.327428, 430.779, 283.99, 0.179039, 433.428, 298.999, 0.031905, 501.41, 308.711, 0.0367349, 488.167, 307.828, 0.07174, 476.689, 314.008, 0.0632121, 439.608, 291.936, 0.0260603, 502.293, 306.945, 0.0131884, 458.149, 292.819, 0.0295078, 477.572, 315.774, 0.0275818, 438.725, 287.521, 0.015142, 458.149, 291.053, 0.0147157, 453.734, 291.936, 0.0167643, 482.869, 317.539, 0.0241303, 440.491, 289.287, 0.0125309, 445.788, 285.756, 0.0302928, 436.959, 286.639, 0.0408061, 423.716, 284.873, 0.0712924],
        "hand_right_keypoints_2d": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        "pose_keypoints_3d": [],
        "face_keypoints_3d": [],
        "hand_left_keypoints_3d": [],
        "hand_right_keypoints_3d": []
    }]
}
```

edit:
So far I've tried using Json Utility but nothing is happening when I hit play..

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class people
{
    public int[] person_id;
    public float[] pose_keypoints_2d;
    public float[] face_keypoints_2d;
    public float[] hand_left_keypoints_2d;
    public float[] hand_right_keypoints_2d;
    public float[] pose_keypoints_3d;
    public float[] face_keypoints_3d;
    public float[] hand_left_keypoints_3d;
    public float[] hand_right_keypoints_3d;
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[Serializable]
public class OpenPoseStructList
{
    public List<people> OpenPoseStruct = new List<people>();

}

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OpenPoseJSONReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public OpenPoseStructList jSONtest2List = new OpenPoseStructList();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        TextAsset asset = Resources.Load("CamA") as TextAsset;
        if (asset != null)
        {
            Debug.Log(asset.text);
            jSONtest2List = JsonUtility.FromJson<OpenPoseStructList>(asset.text);

            foreach (people test in jSONtest2List.OpenPoseStruct)
            {
                Debug.Log(test.person_id.Length);
                Debug.Log(test.pose_keypoints_2d);
                Debug.Log(test.face_keypoints_2d);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("asset is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nested arrays are a standard part of JSON and any functional JSON parser can serialize it. A serializer converts an object to a string, and you already have a string so I don't understand what you are trying to do. Show us what you have tried and why you think MiniJSON can't do it.

Comment: the unity one should also work - if you havent marked all subclasses as serialized that could be why

Comment: [SimpleJSON](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) is another nice library you can use if you don't succeed with your current one. It can handle JSON arrays.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! I updated my post to include the code I've tried.. I need to look deeper into MiniJSON to see its functionality and how to use it and I'll also take a look into SimpleJSON

Comment: Clarify "nothing is happening". Nothing at all or debug output? If nothing at all, have you attached that Script to a GameObject in your scene?

Comment: We use JSON.NET and it works flawlessly with a use case such as yours

Comment: Have you tried to create a unit test that verifies serialization/deserialization? That will make it easier to isolate where the problem is. If you aren't familiar with unit testing https://www.raywenderlich.com/9454-introduction-to-unity-unit-testing has a good introduction specific to Unity,